# linux commands to copy one file to many folders?

Tags: linux, shell

Is there a one-line command/script to copy one file to many folders on linux?

```
cp file folder1 folder2 ... folderN
```

cp file into folder1,folder2,...,folderN, And folder1,folder2,...,folderN in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a single command, but you can easily do something like this (assuming your shell is bash):

```
for d in folder1 folder2 folderN ; do cp file $d/ ; done
```

Comment: Looks like one line to me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something weird like this:

```
echo folder1 folder2 folderN | xargs -n 1 cp file
```

which will execute the following commands:

```
cp file folder1
cp file folder2
cp file folderN
```

I still think @Paul R's solution is the better one, I just think this command is interesting.